# grep not finding ".*" string values

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a file **temp.txt** as below.

```
a.*,super
```

I want to grep `.*` to check whether the value is present in the file or not.

**Command used:**

```
grep -i ".*" temp.txt
```

**returns nothing**

Comment: `man bash`, section `REGULAR EXPRESSIONS`.

Comment: I would expect that command to return every line in the file, rather than nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk '/\.\*/' file
```

or fgrep

```
fgrep ".*" file
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `grep` considers the pattern as a regular expression.

To make `grep` interpret it as a literal, use `-F`.

```
grep -F ".*" temp.txt
```

Also, note `-i` is not needed, because there is no case distinction to take into account (we for example use it to make grep return `AB`, `aB`, `Ab` and `ab` when doing `grep -i "ab"`).

---

As `man grep` says:

> **-F, --fixed-strings**
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines,
>   any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)
>
> **-i, --ignore-case**
>
> Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.  (-i
>   is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: @fedorqui : If i dont want to search it in temp.txt but i want to search in a previous output then , will it work ? `echo "Hello .*|grep -F ".*"`

Comment: Yes, @logan , just do `echo "Hello .*" | grep -F ".*"`. Note you missed a double quote in the first command.

Answer (score 1):

Both `.`, `*` have special meaning in regular expression. Escape them to match literally.

```
$ cat temp.txt
a.*,super
$ grep "\.\*" temp.txt
a.*,super
$ echo $?
0


$ grep "there-is-no-such-string" temp.txt
$ echo $?
1
```

`-i` is not need because there's no alphabet in the regular expression.